# How to structure complex function to apply to col of pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a large (>500k rows) pandas df like so

`orig_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('id', 'free_text1', 'something_inert', 'free_text2'))`

`free_textX` is a string field containing user input imported from a csv. The goal is to have a function `func` that does various checks on each row of `free_textX` and then a performs Levenshtein fuzzy text recognition based on the contents of another df reference. Something like

```py
from rapidfuzz import process
LEVENSHTEIN_DIST = 25

def func(s) -> str:
  if string == "25":
    return s
  elif s == "nothing":
    return "something"
  else:
    s2 = process.extractOne(
           query = s,
           choices = reference['col_name'],
           score_cutoff = LEVENSHTEIN_DIST
           )
    return s2
```

After this process a new column has to be inserted after `free_textX` called `recog_textX` containing the returned values from `func`.

I tried vectorization (for performance) like so

```py
orig_df.insert(loc=new_col_index, #calculated before
               column='recog_textX',
               value=func(orig_df['free_textX'])
               )

def func(series) -> pd.core.series.Series:
  ...
```

but I don't understand how to structure `func` (handling an entire df col as a series, by demand of vectorization, right?) as `process.extractOne(...) -> str` handles single strs instead of a series. Those interface concepts seem incompatible to me. But I do want to avoid a classic iteration here for performance reasons. My grasp of pandas is too shallow here. Help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing a point, but you can use `apply` function to get what I think you want:

```
orig_df['recog_textX'] = orig_df['free_textX'].apply(func)
```

This will create a new column 'recog_textX' by applying your function `func` to each element of the 'free_textX' column.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question

As an aside, I do not think vectorizing this operation will make any difference speed-wise, given each application of `func()` is a complicated string operation. But it does look nicer than just looping through rows

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As far as I understand pandas docu this is no longer clean vectorization? I was using .insert(...) to be able to handle the entire column as one to make this max performant. But then, how can I pass single values out to .extractOne(...)? Apply would work, but is it slower? I don't quite get the step from cols to cells here when vectorizing the access

Comment: well frankly I would not know if this is "clean" or not, I guess you can check if you are happy with the performance. You can also do it using list comprehension: `new_vals = [func(s) for s in df['free_textX']]` and then insert the list `new_vals` into your df as the new column as you were trying to do before. No idea if this has any performance benefits, you can time the two and see (and post here for posterity)

Comment: So it looks like I was dramatically overthinking this... Your solution works, thanks for pointing me back in the right direction. I will come back with timings.